# Error: in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to load a package I have installed via Bioconductor (using BiocLite()) as I have done with many other similar packages from the same source. However I get this error:

```
[Error: package or namespace load failed for 'GenomicFeatures' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/mario/Library/R/3.4/library/rtracklayer/libs/rtracklayer.so':

dlopen(/Users/mario/Library/R/3.4/library/rtracklayer/libs/rtracklayer.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mario/Library/R/3.4/library/rtracklayer/libs/rtracklayer.so

  Reason: image not found]
```

If I try to install and load library `rtracklayer` I get the same message

I've tried reading to answers for similar questions on the site but I still can't figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to install "GenomicFeatures" first.

Comment: I have done that, and the installation gave no error although it said this:   tar: Failed to set default locale